# Conditional formatting lookup column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, formatting

I am attempting to do conditional formatting in a list view in SharePoint Designer.  In this list I have a list that contains a lookup column, and other columns derived from the list of that lookup column.  In the source list, the columns Hours, cycles, APU Hours are all numbers; Date In is a date (asterisks are there to draw attention)

[image: partial view of the columns in my list]

The data in the list/view is pulling correctly, but does not appear to compare when building the condition in SharePoint Designer

The clause in the condition appears as such in xpath notation: `$thisNode/@Due_x0020_Hours. <= @Registration_x003a_Hours_x0020_I`

[image: conditions]

Do lookup columns retain their data types (that is can numbers be compared against other numbers?); and can lookup columns be used in conditional formatting?  Or is there a special notation that has to be used for conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find that the lookup is stored as a link back to the original list item so you will need to remove that additional formatting before you can do a comparison.

Something like this should remove any HTML tag around the value:

```
substring-after(substring-before(@Registration_x003a_Hours_x0020_I,"<"),">")
```

Comment: That is to have "$thisNode/@Max_x0020_Hours. <= /dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Registration_x003a_Cycles_x0020_"  as the only clause/condition?  Doesn't appear to work.  I also tried converting the link to a number, but that doesn't work either

Comment: Put both values on your page and compare the HTML that is actually rendered using something like Developer Tools (F12 in IE).  You will probably find there is an <a> tag surrounding the lookup value so you will need to strip this out.  I have added a suggestion in my response above though it may need some tweaking . . .